# ./create-android-project.sh: line 103: /home/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/sdk/tools/android: No such file or directory

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, shell, android-ndk

I am trying to build project of cocos2dx in my eclipse.whenever I am try to run `./create-android-project.sh` command on my terminal its gives me an error saying :-

```
Now cocos2d-x supports Android 2.2 or upper version 


 ./create-android-project.sh: line 103: /home/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/sdk/tools/android: No such file or directory

input target id:
```

I have made every change as per suggested in this tutorial :- http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

I have changed the following lines :-

```
# set environment paramters

NDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/home/laschweinski/android/android-ndk-r8d"
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/home/laschweinski/android/android-sdk-linux_86"
```

to

```
NDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/home/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/android-ndk-r10d"
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/home/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/sdk"
```

in create-android-project.sh shell script.

have also provided path of my NDK in `build_native.sh`.

Can anyone tell me that where I am lacking in building this project. Any help will be appreciated. I am working on Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add your ndk path to your env ?

Comment: yes, I have added the path of NDK in my eclipse.

Comment: Hey , Thanks man ..I just checked I have added old path of ndk to my .bashrc file...Thanks man because of your  question I compare the path of two that I have declared in Eclipse and that which I declared in my .bashrc file.